# Spellcheck not working in Libre office in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

When I try to run the spell check in Libre office I get the following error.

[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bi30.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I had no languages installed on my system. I installed languages using the Language Support application.

Download the dictionary from here: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries

Open downloaded file and this should generate a window to install the extension.

Shut Libreoffice applications, reopen them and they should all work now.